# Contradicting laws

Tags: jurisdiction

If one law is valid in one jurisdiction say country A Wich says *you must use digital currency on Sundays*  and another law opposing that law is there in another jurdiction say country B which say *you must not use digital currency on Sundays*. A person sitting in one legislation has accepted that the laws of the other legislation applies to him via a contract ( many contracts say "you subject yourself to the exclusive jurisdiction of the court of country B") or those laws apply because he trades (does business which involves a digital currency)  in those countries.What should he do use or not use digital currency on sundays?

Comment: What Jurisdiction are you in?   Your question is still confusing in terminology and some words seem misspelt or misused.

Comment: Which words are you talking about?

Comment: Say you are in an imaginary country enasia  which has a law that s do not use digital currency and you sign an agreement that say you subject yourself to the laws of eukaria another country where

Comment: the law says do use digital currency. The which countries law is to be obeyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should he do use or not use digital currency on sundays?

If I understand correctly, you are asking about a scenario where the parties agree that the governing law will be that of jurisdiction *B* notwithstanding that the contract, or the relevant part thereof, will be performed in jurisdiction *A*.

If *A* and *B* were [in] different countries, the issue *could* depend on what (if any) international treaties binding both countries provide regarding a conflict of laws. Absent any realistic specifics (enasia and eukaria are not realistic), let's assume that *A* means *the U.S.* or is some jurisdiction in the U.S.

The contractually chosen law (jurisdiction *B*) would apply unless doing so contravenes policy restrictions of the jurisdiction where the contract is performed (jurisdiction *A*). Those policy restrictions could be public policy, legislation, or legislative intent that can be inferred from jurisdiction *A*'s laws. For instance, see [*Ticknor v. Choice Hotels Int'l, Inc.*, 265 F.3d 931, 937 (9th Cir. 2011)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/20011196265f3d93111109):

> The law of the state chosen by the parties ... will be applied ...
> unless ... application of the law of the chosen state would be
> contrary to a fundamental policy of a state which has a materially
> greater interest than the chosen state[.]

(citing *Restatement (Second) of Conflict of Laws* at § 187(b)).

Note that discrepancies between *A*'s law and *B*'s law do not necessarily result in a material detriment to *A*'s policy, and it is unclear from your post whether refraining from using digital currency on Sundays would be such case. One would need to ascertain *A*'s public policy and/or legislative intent (if the relevant legislation has been enacted).

Comment: Ok so jurisdiction B should apply.

Comment: @astackexchangeuser Yes as long as it does not contravene the reason of being of A's policy.